# Как создать проект на двух языках?

Tags: python, java, python-3.x

Я относительно недавно начала интересоваться программированием, всего лишь полтора года. И недавно мы с другом решили создать проект в команде. Но когда возник вопрос на чём писать, стало понятно, что бэкенд мы будем писать на python. А фронтенд хотелось бы написать на Jav'e.

Так вот в чём вопрос, возможно ли сделать так, чтобы фронт полностью работал на Jav'e а бэк на Python'e, если да, то предложите, какую-нибудь статью или литературу, по теме объединения нескольких языков в одном проекте.

Comment: Вы не знакомы с предметом, к сожалению. Нет трудности в том что фронт и бек работали на разных языках. Технология так устроена, что не важно какие языки в какой части.

Comment: Может быть все же на JavaScript фронт?

Comment: @Nofate, фронт не обязательно браузер.

Comment: А обязательно ваш сайт разделять на фронт и бэк?

Comment: Вы случайно не путаете Java и Javascript?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотря что вы хотите, если вы хотите в браузере то клиент (фронт) на Java будет осуществлен через Spring Boot - https://habr.com/ru/company/piter/blog/668616/
(ещё так же ищите как использовать thymeleaf с spring boot)
но код страницы все равно будете писать на HTML/JS/CSS (разметка для браузера)

Если просто приложение на Java то там всё проще

если вы хотите фронт на Python то используйте Python Django - https://habr.com/ru/post/240463/

не важно на каком языке написан фронт и бэк на разных или одном, связать их можно с помощью следующих способов:
1. Socket (в браузере WebSocket)
2. http запросы

Пример 1:
Сервер (бэк), написанный на Python:

```
import socket


def server_program():
    # get the hostname
    host = "localhost"  # socket.gethostname()
    port = 9999

    server_socket = socket.socket()

    server_socket.bind((host, port))

    # configure how many client the server can listen simultaneously
    server_socket.listen(2)
    conn, address = server_socket.accept()  # accept new connection
    print("Connection from: " + str(address))
    while True:
        # receive data stream. it won't accept data packet greater than 1024 bytes
        data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
        if not data:
            # if data is not received break
            break
        print("from connected user: " + str(data))
        spl = str(data).split(";")
        # check auth
        if spl[0] == "auth":
            login = spl[1];
            password = spl[2]
            if login == "admin" and password == "11111":
                conn.send("auth;true\n".encode())


    conn.close()  # close the connection


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_program()
```

Клиент написанный на Java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientConnection {
    public int port = 9999;
    public String host = "localhost";

    public Socket socket = null;
    public BufferedReader read = null;
    public BufferedWriter out = null;

    public Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
                String message = null;
                try {
                    message = read.readLine();
                   // if(message!=null){
                        System.out.println(message);

                        String []split = message.split(";");
                        if(split[0].equals("auth")){
                            if(split[1].equals("true")){
                                System.out.println("Авторизация прошла успешно");
                            }
                        }
                   // }
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                    break;
                }

            }
        }
    });

    public void send(String string) {
        try {
            out.write(string);
            out.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public ClientConnection() {
        try {
            socket = new Socket(host, port);
            read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            thread.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        ClientConnection clientConnection = new ClientConnection();
        /*while(true){
            String string = scanner.nextLine();
            if(string!=null){
                clientConnection.send(string);
            }
        }*/
        //Пример авторизации:
        clientConnection.send("auth;admin;11111");
    }

}
```

Так же тут представлена простейшая авторизация.

Пример 2:
http сервер на Python:

```
import http.server
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from http.server import HTTPServer
import socketserver

PORT = 8080


class HttpGetHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    """Обработчик с реализованным методом do_GET."""

    def do_GET(self):
        #print("GET request for {}".format(self.path).encode('utf-8'))
        param = (str(self.path)).replace("/?","").split("&")
        if param[0].split("=")[1]=="admin" and param[1].split("=")[1]=="11111":
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write('auth;true'.encode())
            return

        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('auth;false'.encode())


Handler = HttpGetHandler

with socketserver.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler) as httpd:
    print("serving at port", PORT)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Клиент на Java:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.Buffer;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ClientConnection {

    public static String stream(URL url) throws IOException {
        try (InputStream input = url.openStream()) {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(input);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
            StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
            int c;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                json.append((char) c);
            }
            return json.toString();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException {
        String auth = stream(new URL("http://localhost:8080/?login=admin&password=11111"));
        String []spl = auth.split(";");
        if(spl[0].equals("auth")){
            if(spl[1].equals("true")){
                System.out.println("Авторизация успешна");
            }
        }
    }
}
```